# A RenderFlex overflowed by 99888 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have met some issue on my "HomeScreen" but it's work before not sure what's going on it's not working right now. Also have a doubt there because I've been add a container and the column also inside of the container why the column will overflow?

I would like to have a "Container" for display image on left side and right side for display "UserInformation" that fetch from database however it's showing column issue even though have been added "Flexible" or "Expanded" also not working.

[image: Home Screen]

**"HomeScreen Display"**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profile = Provider.of<UserProfileLogic>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                "assets/images/Materials-25.png",
              ),
              radius: 70,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: profile.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(profile.items[i].username),
                      Text(profile.items[i].age.toString()),
                      Text(profile.items[i].gender),
                      Text(profile.items[i].bio),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      UserProfileItem(profile.items[i].userprofileid),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**"UserProfileItem.dart"**
The reason why creating this because I have to pass argument of "ID" to make sure once user click for the button and it will get the ID so once going for "ProfileScreen" could see his own profile.

```
    class UserProfileItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;

  UserProfileItem(this.id);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Profile"),
      elevation: 6,
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        ProfileScreen.routeName,
        arguments: id,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**"After Used Solution "** May I know why it will display out? Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have your `ListView.builder` as the child of a `Column()` and Columns does not scroll, change that column for a `ListView` and your issue sould be solved.

Also check if you are trying to access a null value and provide a default value for the text widget, a text widget's data can not be null.

```
      Flexible(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: profile.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.username ?? "No username"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.age?.toString()  ?? "No age"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.gender ?? "No gender"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.bio ?? "No bio"),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  UserProfileItem(profile.items[i].userprofileid),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Regarding the duplicate list you get, check hat the value of profile.items.length is, because you are using that as the itemCount.

Comment: does it not work after adding the default values?

Comment: What is default value that you mean?

Comment: What sajith lakmal said in the other answer "Text(profile?.items[i]?.username ?? "No user name")," no user name is a default value you are giving in case the other one is null

Comment: yeap, it's working, however after combination of two solution it's does not have error occurs but it will display "No username" "NO..".... below the button

Comment: Whats the error you get after adding the default values and changing the column for a ListView?

Comment: It's no error anymore but it duplicate again "No username ", "No age", "No gender" , "No Bio" and a "Profile" button at bottom, I'll update the image on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233704/discussion-between-chinbin-and-jaime-ortiz).

Answer (score 2):

Overflow is not the problem. overflow is caused by the error widget in flutter.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profile = Provider.of<UserProfileLogic>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                "assets/images/Materials-25.png",
              ),
              radius: 70,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: profile.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.username ?? "No user name"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.age?.toString()  ?? "No age"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.gender ?? "No gender"),
                  Text(profile?.items[i]?.bio ?? "No bio"),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      UserProfileItem(profile.items[i].userprofileid),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that you have null value in your items fields. To solve this change your text widgets as above.

Comment: You are right, i just asumed the problem was the lenght of the list

Comment: I've tried what you mention but's it's not working and once add  "??  No user name" it will also display at the bottom of "profile.items[i].username"

Comment: Can you provide UserProfieItem's build method?

Comment: Have been updated on the questions, I'm not sure is it problem of vs code because previously it's work however I didn't change any part of code of there. From the picture, it already show the info that store so I'm not really clear what do you mean by have null value in my item field...

Comment: I have changed the answer there was a typo in my answer

Comment: Ya, I know but it's still not working as well.

Error:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 54 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib/profile/user_profile_display.dart:29
You can inspect this widget using the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification.
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Comment: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#595eb relayoutBoundary=up7 OVERFLOWING